# overcharging issues in MPPT solar controller with NO output leads

Tags: solar-cell, load, mppt, controller, panel

[image: Typical representation of MPPT charge controller system]My MPPT solar controller has no output leads. It contains only the (+,-)leads for battery and solar panel. Input is from the solar panel and output goes to battery.Therefore, I have to connect my load to battery connections. Output from 2 PV is 23 V and output from 60 A rated charge controller is 13 V. MPPT controller doubles the current from the PV's.

I want to know, how solar controller will manage overcharging/discharging related tasks of battery. What are the chances that my battery will not be overcharged. Can I take any other measures. My load is 12 V dc.Thanks

Comment: It depends entirely on the controller. This can't be answered unless you can give more details and references to the MPPT controller.

Comment: Ensure your MPPT is configured correctly for your battery. Then it will protect against overcharging. You'll need a separate means to protect against over-discharging. (Some loads - e.g. inverters - will cut off automatically at your choice of battery voltage. Some kinds of batteries e.g. LiFePO4 should be configured with a BMS to do that)

Answer (score 1):

Unless it measures current for Batt. separate from load there is no provision to detect loading during CC, CV, floating and cutoff control if Lithium.  Thus it is not intended to be loaded during CV so it goes forever if the load is > cutoff which is usually 5 % to 10% of CC.

BUT for SLA and car batteries you only have CV with possibly thermal control of CV and floating for SLA.

Show all datasheets of every box.  In short, a smart controller has 2 control functions, MPPT for source and another for output regulation with 2 outputs; Bat and load.   Yours only has 1 output not 2.  So float voltage is the safest.

- lead Acid batteries can be left at 14.2 if solar power is available, then load sensing is your option with an
  ammeter